# NSUserNotificationCenter: is it enabled?

Tags: objective-c, notifications

On MacOS 10.8, how can it be determined if Notification Center is enabled or not? I need to know this to choose how to notify the user.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. Also, I'd guess that users who disable notifications for your app really don't want to be notified, so you should respect that and not try to work around it.

Comment: I understand, even if choosing not to be notified probably isn't a smart choice.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into the `userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:` delegate method. Haven't tried it, and the documentation is a bit vague, but it might be worth a try: "Sent to the delegate when the user notification center has decided not to present your notification."

Comment: If an app implements this method returning "YES" (for example), after having set itself as the delegate for the user notification center, every notification will be shown even if the app is in the foreground (while the standard behavior is showing notifications only when the sender app is in the background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read out Notification Center's sqlite database stored at ~/Lbrary/Application Support/NotificationCenter/, which stores the info whether the user has enabled the Notification Center for an app or not. Sample code available [here](https://github.com/timschroedernet/ncMeta).